# Is it possible to redirect in the middle of an alert box?

Tags: javascript, redirect, alert

I have an alert box that pops up, warning the user that they will be redirected soon.
However, redirection only happens *after* they click OK.

I want redirection to happen *while* the alert box is popped up, not *after*. Also, there should also be enough time for the user to read the alert in the first place (I allowed 2.5s). Any advice?

Code below:

```
setTimeout("redir()", 2500);
alert("You are being redirected.");

function redir () {
    window.location = "target.php";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard alert box halts page execution, so you can't redirect while it's showing. The user has to first press ok. 
You have to come up with a custom message if you want this behavior.

You can have a look at a library called toastR https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

It lets you define callbacks for when a message is shown/hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dialog box instead of the native alert box. For example, jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

don't use an alert.  display a note via a div or span on top of the page... you aren't waiting for their input/acceptance of the fact they are being redirected.